# Mongoose: only one unique boolean key should be true

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two schema collections:

```
Campaigns:{
   _id: "someGeneratedID"
   //...a lot of key value pairs.
   //then i have teams which is an, array of teams from the Team schema.
   teams:teams: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Team" }],
}

Teams:{
    campaignId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Campaign" },
    isDefault: { type: Boolean, default: false },
}
```

Now I would like that when I add teams to the collection, it should throw an error if there are more than 2 `isDefault:true` per `campaignId`.

so the following shouldn't be allowed:

```
teams:[
   {
    campaignId:1,
    teamName:"John Doe"
    isDefault:true,
   }
   {
    campaignId:1,
    teamName:"Jane Doe"
    isDefault:true
   }
]
```

I found this answer on SO:

```
teamSchema.index(
  { isDefault: 1 },
  {
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: { isDefault: true },
  }
```

But couldn't manage to also check for the campaignId.

Thanks in advance.

ps: can you also provide an explanation for what's happening in the index method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simplest way to approach this is via Mongoose's middleware `pre('save')`. This method will give you a way to check all the campaigns listed in the collection in order to check if any of the items is already set as default.

```
teamSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  try {
    if ((this.isNew || this.isModified("isDefault") && this.isDefault) {
      const previousDefault = await mongoose.models["Team"].findOne({ isDefault: true, campaignId: this.campaignId });
      if (previousDefault) {
        throw new Error('There is already default team for this campaign');
      }
    }
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
});
```

This way, if any team, either new or already existing, is set as default for a given campaign, before its record is saved, the whole collection will be searched for any entry with `isDefault` already set to `true`. If at least one item is found, we will throw an error. If not, `next()` guarantees the save() method will go on.

Comment: A little misunderstanding here. there are a lot of campaigns. and a lot of teams. but there should be one `isDefault: true` team per campaign.

Comment: I see. But the solution is not so different: you only have to make your query a little bit more precise. Check the edits I just added

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there are a few changes to make to your answer, if you could edit: `Teams.pre` => `teamSchema.pre`. `this.isDefault.isModifed` => `this.isModified("isDefault")`. `this.model.findOne` => `mongoose.models["Team"].findOne`. this is what worked for me, the others either didn't work or threw errors. thanks